# Matplotlib installation for python 3.6. and windows 8

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, installation

I do not understand exactly what I should do to install Matplotlib. I read a lot of posts but I do not have so much of fluent knowledge in programming so basically all of this that i read is quite confusing.  Does anyone know what exactly should be done when having Python 3.6., visual code studio and Windows 8 to install Matplotlib?

Comment: If you're just getting started and need to do scientific Python work try installing Anaconda.  It is generally the easiest way for a beginner to get up and running because it will already have Matplotlib installed.  It's what we use in most Software Carpentry workshops.  I say this now because this question will probably get deleted or closed since SO is not really a good place to ask beginner questions.

Comment: Oh, okay, i didnt know that this is not for begginers also. Thanks anyway, i will try your suggestion.

Comment: I mean it is and it isn't.  You'll want to look at what types of questions are/aren't allowed: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic  But anyways, Anaconda is a Python distribution specifically for getting started with a scientific Python toolchain.

Comment: Quick note: Stackoverflow is for absolute beginners as well as professionals.So please don't feel intimidated. The main point is more that there are rules to follow, which beginners often have difficulties with. While you are in general strongly invited to ask a question here, make sure that is according to [the guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). This question here is too broad, it does not have a specific problem desciption (other than you not knowing what to do), maybe even opinion based, possibly asking for software recommendations (all three things are not suited for SO).

Comment: Thank you, i will check it out! :) It Is true that begginers feel difficulities at beggining - because you dont have feeling exactly what is good, or not so good. But these answers were also needed in order for me to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way that is simple using the original python from python.org with PATH installed is to use pip. You can check by opening cmd and entering python. If it is not a recognised command then you will have to reinstall python but make sure to tick the box at the start to enable PATH. once this is done you can install packages such as numpy and matplotlib.

In cmd type `pip install` Then the package you want to install from the [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi) website and using the **EXACT** name in the url before the version number. It should be like: /PACKAGE/VERSION.
eg. for matplotlib the url is /**matplotlib**/VERSION, so the name would be matplotlib. To install the latest version `pip install matplotlib`
If for some reason you want to uninstall a package you would do: `pip uninstall PACKAGE`. To install a specific version use `pip install PACKAGE==VERSION` where VERSION is the exact version name in the url. For full documentation visit [Packaging Help](https://packaging.python.org/).

Visual code studio is not necessary in this situation. This question is too broad and asking for a recommendation on software. Because of this, I went with the original python installation way and not any 3rd party software.

Comment: Thank you! I succesfully installed it :)